# Restricting GeoServer to OpenLayers on localhost?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I'm publishing WMS-Layer with GeoServer that should be accessible only by an OpenLayers client running on the same machine.
The OpenLayers map is not public and I want to restrict also the WMS delivered by GeoServer so that it should only be visible to users accessing the layer through our OpenLayers client.

Since I'm new to GeoServer I actually don't see another way to achieve this, but there might be other and even better ways to restrict the access to the WMS-layers from GeoServer?

What should I try?

Comment: Unplug the machine from the network?

Comment: OK, its so simple and effective that I didn't even consider it. Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, it seems that you are saying that no users on any other PCs will ever access this OpenLayers/GeoServer map.  Is this correct?  Or do you mean that the OpenLayers web app is being served out on the same PC as the GeoServer, but may need be accessed using a web browser on other PCs?

Answer (score 1):

Not good answer sarcastic unplug network, what are that??

You do firewall on machine you say port GeoServer disallow then you want just layer you use reverse proxy you write if from IP localhost and also user-agent what you say is you then allow layer others you return from proxy 401 or even more 403 if folder no have authentication.